# how to login to one of the node of the aks cluster and get into the shell

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to find a way to ssh to aks nodes of the cluster. Is there a procedure someone can share?

or it is possible if i login to one node of the cluster and i can ssh to other nodes using simple ssh @ command?

Comment: have you used `--ssh-key-value` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-create or a similar option at create time?

Comment: my bad! no. i did not use --ssh-key-value